# Windows 8 Metro does not launch, "The process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app didn't start'."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've been developing a metro app on my personal laptop at home for the office showroom that's going to have a slideshow and the option to request a callback/leave contact details; Most of it is done, my issue is that when I uploaded the project to Dropbox so that I could load it up on the office computer, it refuses to launch. It doesn't throw an exception, instead it displays these message boxes:
This is a C# Windows 8 Metro application built upon the BasicPage template.

```
[TITLE]Lexar2.exe - This application could not be started[/TITLE]

[CONTENT]
This application could not be started.

Do you want to view information about this issue?

[/CONTENT]

[BUTTONS]Yes/No[/BUTTONS]




[TITLE]Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8[/TITLE]

[CONTENT]
Unable to activate Windows Store app '...!App'. The Lexar2.exe process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app didn't start'.
[/CONTENT]
```

Program output:

```
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Programming\w8\Lexar2\Lexar2\bin\Debug\AppX\Lexar2.exe'. 
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x5c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreeis.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\tiptsf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Lexar2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x189c has exited with code -2146232576 (0x80131700).
The thread 0x19f8 has exited with code -2146232576 (0x80131700).
The thread 0x1370 has exited with code -2146232576 (0x80131700).
The thread 0x10ec has exited with code -2146232576 (0x80131700).
The program '[6224] Lexar2.exe' has exited with code -2146232576 (0x80131700).
```

I can't think of anything else that would need to be added other than system specs so please tell me if I'm leaving something out:

```
Windows 8 x64
6GB Ram
Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G2020 2.9Ghz
```

Edit: I am able to create a new project and launch that without issues, and the app I'm working on now was originally created on this computer and uploaded to dropbox, where I downloaded it on my personal laptop and worked on it overnight than re-uploaded it.

Comment: My general understanding is that this is vaguely intended, but not well-presented to the user. Unlike standard desktop apps, W8 apps cannot be traded around freely; there is a relatively complex "side-loading" process required to run a non-Store-published W8 app on a non-development machine, and you need to have Windows 8 Enterprise.

Comment: Shoot, that's annoying; guess I'll just finish it on the personal and start transferring over code, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: WinRT imposes a hard upper limit on how long an app can take before it becomes responsive to the user. Not quite sure what the limit is, but if you are not displaying a "I'm busy, working on it" kind of rotating dots after a second or two then you'll be automatically put in the dog house. That dog house also includes failing the certification test.  It is supposed to be "fast and fluid", the async/await keywords added to C# version 5 are instrumental.

Answer (score 0):

This has the answer for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241613.aspx

Alternatively, when you publish your project in Visual Studio from the Project > Store > Create App Packages menu, you get the APPX together with a PowerShell script for the installation. Make sure you have a dev license on the target machine before installing.